# Setting React array state doesn't update it at all

Tags: reactjs, arrays, state, setstate

I've been stuck with this idea of setting the array to an empty one after the function fires, but no matter what I did the results were the same. I want to empty an array if it contains the element that was pressed, but It keeps logging the old array, making it impossible to check if array already contains it in the first place. I'm new to React and I've already tried using useEffect() but I don't understand it that much even after studying and trying to use it several times.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Card } from "./Card";
import "../styles/Playboard.css";
import { Scoreboard } from "./Scoreboard";

export function Playboard(props) {
  const [score, setScore] = useState(0);
  const [bestScore, setBestScore] = useState(0);

  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState([]);
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([
    <Card name="A" key={1} handleCardClick={handleCardClick}></Card>,
    <Card name="B" key={2} handleCardClick={handleCardClick}></Card>,
    <Card name="C" key={3} handleCardClick={handleCardClick}></Card>,
    <Card name="D" key={4} handleCardClick={handleCardClick}></Card>,
    <Card name="E" key={5} handleCardClick={handleCardClick}></Card>,
    <Card name="F" key={6} handleCardClick={handleCardClick}></Card>,
  ]);

  const increment = () => {
    setScore((c) => c + 1);
  };

  function checkScore() {
    if (score > bestScore) {
      setBestScore(score);
    }
  }

  function handleStateChange(state) {
    setClicked(state);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setCards(shuffleArray(cards));
    handleStateChange();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCards(shuffleArray(cards));
    checkScore();
  }, [score]);

  function handleCardClick(e) {
    console.log(clicked);
    if (clicked.includes(e.target.querySelector("h1").textContent)) {
      console.log(clicked);
      resetGame();
    } else {
      increment();
      clicked.push(e.target.querySelector("h1").textContent);
      console.log(clicked);
    }
  }

  function resetGame() {
    setScore(0);
    setClicked([]);
    console.log(clicked);
  }

  const shuffleArray = (array) => {
    return [...array].sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="container">{cards}</div>
      <Scoreboard score={score} bestScore={bestScore}></Scoreboard>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Never put JSX elements in state! Just put data there and render your elements based on it.

Comment: Also, you really shouldn't (need to) do `e.target.querySelector()` with React.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a memory game of sorts, where you have to remember which cards you've clicked and they shuffle after every click? Okay!

As my comment says, you *don't* want to put JSX elements in state; state should be just data, and you render your UI based on that.

Here's a cleaned-up version of your game ([here on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-resonance-i8lbqq)) –

- `Card` is a simple component that renders the name of the card, and makes sure clicking the button calls `handleCardClick` with the name, so you need not read it from the DOM.
- `shuffleArray` doesn't need to be in the component, so it's... not.
- `initializeCards` returns a shuffled copy of the A-F array.
- `useState(initializeCards)` takes advantage of the fact that `useState` allows a function initializer; i.e. `initializeCards` will be called once by React when Playboard mounts.
- `useEffect` is used to (possibly) update `bestScore` when `score` updates. You don't really need it for anything else in this.
- `cards.map(... => <Card...>)` is the usual React idiom to take data and turn it into elements.
- I'm using `JSON.stringify()` here as a poor man's scoreboard plus debugging tool (for `clicked`).
- I'm making liberal use of the [functional update form](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) of `setState` for efficiency (not that it matters a lot in this).

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function Card({ name, handleCardClick }) {
  return <button onClick={() => handleCardClick(name)}>{name}</button>;
}

function shuffleArray(array) {
  return [...array].sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
}

function initializeCards() {
  return shuffleArray(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]);
}

function Playboard() {
  const [score, setScore] = useState(0);
  const [bestScore, setBestScore] = useState(0);
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState([]);
  const [cards, setCards] = useState(initializeCards);

  useEffect(() => {
    setBestScore((bestScore) => Math.max(bestScore, score));
  }, [score]);

  function handleCardClick(name) {
    if (clicked.includes(name)) {
      resetGame();
    } else {
      setScore((c) => c + 1);
      setClicked((c) => [...c, name]);
      setCards((cards) => shuffleArray(cards));
    }
  }

  function resetGame() {
    setScore(0);
    setClicked([]);
    setCards(initializeCards());
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="container">
        {cards.map((name) => (
          <Card name={name} key={name} handleCardClick={handleCardClick} />
        ))}
      </div>
      {JSON.stringify({ score, bestScore, clicked })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you quality of code advices and how to use things I've been using more efficiently! I can see now why my previous version didn't work as intended, and I will surely stick to your advices for my future projects.